# AWS CloudWatch log stream is empty while Docker container logs are full

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cron, amazon-ecs

I'm creating cron docker image, based on ubuntu image. I would use [this](https://lostindetails.com/articles/How-to-run-cron-inside-Docker) tutorial,
but cron won't have PID 1, not 2 and not even 10. I found a solution to
run cron in foreground, check it using healthcheck and view logs of command using `tail -f`
Locally all is perfect, but when I deploy it to ECS Fargate logs are empty

**Main issue**

`docker logs -f cron` displays output, but
logs in cloudwatch are empty

**Additional information**

I created Dockerfile with following ENTRYPOINT and CMD

```
COPY crontab /etc/crontab
COPY script.sh /root/script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["tini", "--", "/usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD prepare.sh tail -f /var/log/script.log
```

`prepare.sh` content:

```sh
# some preparation commands...
cron -L 15
exec "$@"
```

`docker-entrypoint.sh` also has at the end `exec "$@"`.

`crontab` content:

```
*/3 *  * * * root /root/script.sh >> /var/log/script.log
```

So, the last command is `tail -f /var/log/script.log`

Answer (score 2):

In order for your container's logs to appear in CloudWatch logs, you need to setup your Task Definition to use the `awslogs` log driver.

Documentation on how to do this [can be found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html).